# Identifying C/C++ Library Functions

Tags: c++, ghidra, c, dos, dos-exe

I am attempting to reverse-engineer an old DOS executable, which seems to have been compiled around 1992 using Microsoft's C compiler at the time.

When opening the executable in Ghidra no imports are listed, so I assume that any library functions that were utilised have been statically linked. Certain strings exist such as `%s%s`, so I can assume that `printf` has been utilised, for example.

However, when looking through the code, nothing stands out as obviously being library code. Is there a way to identify library functions just from looking at the assembly/decompiled output?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of [FLIRT](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/tech/flirt/) signatures.

There's a [Python script](https://github.com/NWMonster/ApplySig) porting IDA FLIRT for Ghidra. You can use existing signature sets, for instance [github.com/Maktm/FLIRTDB](https://github.com/Maktm/FLIRTDB) (or make and apply your own signatures if needed).

If you need a tutorial on Ghidra setup [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgGha_zLqlo)'s a decent one.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll look into FLIRT signatures. I've added the script to Ghidra, I just need to locate some 16-bit signature sets now. THanks.